# How to calculate realtime indicators to use at stock market analysis?

Tags: python, finance, ta-lib

I would like to replicate the https://chartink.com/ and I saw some indicator filters at Scan menu and I am looking how to replicate it programatically. I found the talib and pandas-ta library but I have not found a way to replicate their kind of filter.

Once you acess "Create Scan", there is a possibility to chose some indicators and run a scan. How could I do some simulation similar to that, using the RSI indicator for example? Can anyone help with one easy example?